# How to apply a style to Combobox Template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a usercontrol which is multiselect combobox(i.e comoboxitems are checkboxes). I have a common style for every regular combo box in my application. The style is working fine for every combo box except the control I have created. When I comment out combobox template I am able to see the combobox style. The issue is incorporating combobox.template section and have the application style.

[image]

```
   <!--  ComboBox  -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Background}" />
    <!--  <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White"/>  -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground}" />

    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource Controls.FocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                              Background="Transparent"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Focusable="false"
                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Highlighted}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Disabled}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Disabled}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Background.Disabled}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


   <Style x:Key="Controls.ComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Background}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource Controls.FocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="MS Sans Serif" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10pt" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Code:ExtendedProperties.CornerRadius" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

                <Grid x:Name="grid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="3,0,0,3"
                            Padding="1"
                            MinHeight="20">
                        <Border x:Name="SelectedItemBorder" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="3"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      Visibility="Visible">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Margin="3"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                             FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                             FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                             FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                             ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.ContextMenu}"
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly,
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}"
                             Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <!--<Path x:Name="DiffHighlighter" Visibility="Hidden" Data="M18.137,15.136 L18.137,3 C18.137,1.3431458 16.793854,0 15.137,0 L3,0 z" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="8.512" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="8.513">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource quaBlueLightColor}" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" />
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>-->
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="transparentToggleButton"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource TransparentComboBoxButtonStyle}" />
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="dropDownToggleButton"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                  Style="{StaticResource Controls.ComboBox.Button}"
                                  Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid}"
                                  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid}">

                        <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" />
                            <!--<ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                                            CenterY="0.5"
                                            ScaleX="1.1"
                                            ScaleY="1.1" />-->
                        </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           AllowsTransparency="True"
                           Focusable="False"
                           IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Placement="Bottom">
                        <!--PopupAnimation="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"-->
                        <Border MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                                   ElementName=grid}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Padding="0 2 0 0">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer"
                                              Code:ExtendedProperties.CornerRadius="{Binding Path=(Code:ExtendedProperties.CornerRadius),
                                                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <Grid Margin="3">
                                        <Canvas Width="0"
                                                Height="0"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                                                       ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                       Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                                                        ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                       Fill="{Binding Background,
                                                                      ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Highlighted}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectedItemBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Background.Highlighted}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.HighlightedContrast}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Disabled}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="dropDownToggleButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="transparentToggleButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectedItemBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectedItemBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="transparentToggleButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="SelectedItemBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border.Highlighted}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Highlighted}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition SourceName="dropDownToggleButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border.Highlighted}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Highlighted}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border.Highlighted}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Highlighted}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border.Highlighted}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.HighlightedContrast}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Foreground.Disabled}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Background.Disabled}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Control.Border.Disabled}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


 <UserControl x:Class="MultiSelectComboBox.MultiSelectComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         >
       <ComboBox
        x:Name="MultiSelectCombo"  
        Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"
                          Click="CheckBox_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.Template >
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox" >
                <Grid >
                    <ToggleButton 
                        x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Focusable="false"                           
                        ClickMode="Press" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border
                                        x:Name="Border" 
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        CornerRadius="2"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                    <Border 
                                        x:Name="BorderComp" 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        CornerRadius="2" 
                                        Margin="1" 
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="3" />
                                    </Border>

                                    <Path 
                                        x:Name="Arrow"
                                        Grid.Column="1"     
                                        Fill="White"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"                        
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                                Name="DropDown"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Template>
    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

The expected result is that the combobox  is supposed to take on the style that is in the application which is the all black combobox

Comment: Can you post the XAML or C# code where it "Applies styles in the UserControl.Resources"? But it sounds like the visual changes in the style are being applied by the template in that style. When you replace that template with a different one, you should expect the template to be different.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean the style for the combobox is defined somewhere else. If I had a simple combobox in  the usercontrol and nothing more. The style will be applied. Its just the control template that throws things off. Right now I dont have UserControl Resource tags

Comment: There is a line of text in your question which reads **"Applies styles in the UserControl.Resources"**. The meaning of that line is unclear. But I think that's not the issue anyway. The issue is that if you want the replacement template to look like the original, you'll have to alter the replacement template to look like the original. **Can you show us the default style, including the template which it applies to every other ComboBox?**

Comment: I removed the Applies Style to usercontrol res bec it was a mistake. What I am trying to do is apply the application style combobox the black and blue second image to the Multiselectcombobox. I am trying to give you the resource dictionary code but it is to big and wont allow all of it

Comment: Well, maybe you could just paste in the parts of the resource dictionary I asked for. Let's not worry about the "Applies Style". I'm not familiar with those, and unfortunately I'm unable to parse what you're telling me about it.

Comment: I ve added resourcedictionary for the combobox. I didnt create it.

Comment: You should copy the default ControlTemplate as use that as the basis of the one in your UserControl. Alter as needed. Or is that what you already did?